# batch script: including filehandle %%i in DO (subfunction

Tags: file, function, batch-file, parameter-passing, handle

I'm a bit stuck and need some advice.

I start by doing a FOR loop with %%i as the file variable.

```
for %%i in ("C:\*.*") do (
call :function1 "%%i"
goto function2
goto :eof
)
```

the problem is that the file-parameter isn't given to function one..

I have tested with putting an '*echo my echo is %%*' in function1 and i get:

```
my echo is %i
```

And exacltle the same for the use of %%i in function2

Does anyone has advice for me?  How do i get the file handle to be taken to function in the DO form? By the way, this is windows batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("C:\*.*") do (
  call :f "%%i"
)
pause
exit

:f
echo %1
```

Comment: Yes, thanx for your answer but the problem is, in the subfucntions, I make some sets. If I would have %%i to be my handle, than i could do these SETS: SET "filename=#.%~n1" (to take 1th part of filename delimted by dot), SET "ext=%~x1 ... see my problem? How would I call those when the handle already became %1? Suggestions?

Comment: %%i and also %1 accepts the same modifiers, you could call a function with call :func "%%~xi" or use in your function "%~x1"

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the source of my nightmares and it was pretty simple. The solution mentioned by belisarius was good but it did made the rest of my code unusable.

So on the the solution:

```
for %%i in ("C:\*.*") do (
call :function1 "%%~i"
call :function2 "%%~i"
```

That's right! Damn brackets!! But that's a new lesson learnd ;)
Thanx for your time Belisarius